# DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library:

Tags: robotframework, cx-oracle

Using Robot Framework

> DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library:
>   "C:\Software\Oracle\product\12201_Client64\bin\oci.dll is not the
>   correct architecture"

```
Python 3.7.3
cx_Oracle 7.3.0
Robot Framework DatabaseLibrary installed
```

As you can see we have the 64 bit client installed, RF DatabaseLibrary installed.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running the 32-bit version of Python 3.7.3 and this is why it's expecting a 32-bit Oracle driver.

In the [cx_Oracle Installation guide](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files):

> Download an Oracle 19, 18, 12, or 11.2 “Basic” or “Basic Light” zip
>   file: 64-bit or 32-bit, matching your Python architecture.

So, your solution is a choice, install an additional version of Python to match the 64 bit Oracle Client or install a 32-bit Oracle client to match your Python setup.

Comment: Yep - reinstalled the 64bit Python, pip'd in all the Robot Framework and cx_oracle stuff and boom! Thanks much.

Answer (score -1):

You must have the Oracle Client (32 bit)

Dont't forget to put it in the environment variables.